# File is replacing file, not adding in React (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, next.js

Please review my code first.

```js
const test = () => {

const [files, setFiles] = useState ([]);

//I think I have to edit following statement.

const handleFile = (e) => {
   const newFiles = []
   for (let i=0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
       newFiles.push(e.target.files[i])
    }
        setFiles(newFiles)
};

return (

   {files.map((file, index) => (
     <div>
       <div key={index}>
         <p>
         {file.name}
         </p>
         <Button size='small' onClick={() => {deleteSelectedFile(file.name)}}>
         Delete
         </Button>
       </div>
     </div>
    ))}

    <div>
        <label onChange={handleFile}>
            <input type='file' multiple />+ Attach File
        </label>
    </div>

)

}
```

with handleFile statement, I can appropriately get the files.

However, when I upload one file at a time and then upload one file again,

the file is not added. the file replaces file.

**There is not problem when I upload multiple time at once.**

For example, I upload 'hello.jpg', and it renders well in the screen. Then, I upload 'goodbye.jpg', it renders well, but 'goodbye.jpg' replaces 'hello.jpg'.

Therefore, what I see is just 'goodbye.jpg' [button], not

'hello.jpg' [button]
'goodbye.jpg' [button]

.

I want my files to stacked up, without replacing.

I need some wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you only need to spread the prev state values and the files during the change event.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // This is what you need
    setFiles((prev) => [...prev, ...Object.values(e.target.files)]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label onChange={handleChange}>
        <input type="file" multiple />
      </label>
      {files.map((file) => {
        return <p>{file.name}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Wow. this works so well. Can you tell me little more how your statement works? I'm totally lost but so glad it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can use a function inside the setState function to get the current state value and return whatever you want to replace the state. What you want here is the current value of the state + the value you added. So, you just need to return the merged arrays => [prev, current]

Answer (score 0):

how about you don't create a new variable for new files, you just set the state for the files since it's an array

```
setFiles(oldFile => [...oldFile,e.target.files[i]]);
```

If it's possible you can drop a codepen link

Comment: Thank you so much. I learned a lot. I never thought about this way.

Comment: sure , you are welcome